# How to handle age restriction Youtube Data API 3.0

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm developing an android apk which plays some Youtube videos.

I'm using Youtube Data API 3.0 and the videos are playing fine. But some videos has age restriction and the Youtube Player asks to sign in.

I tried to use Google Play Services to authenticate into youtube.

```
GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly");
```

And then, after receive this token I request access to Youtube:

```
    URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&mine=true&access_token=" + token);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    int sc = con.getResponseCode();
```

The authentication screen appears normally, and I receive a JSON with just some tags: kind, etag, pageInfo, items.

Am I using the wrong scope? And what should I do with the received JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize GoogleAccountCredential as in [YouTube Direct Lite example](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android/blob/master/src/com/google/ytdl/MainActivity.java#L124).

Comment: I checked your code, you are using GoogleAccountCredential to load the uploaded video list. But in your PlayActivity, which actually plays the video, you are not using credentials. Is it going to work with videos which are age restricted?

Comment: Yes, it's using simple API access instead which relies on YouTube Android player to handle authentication. That's connected with YouTube app in Android device. So user has to sign in in their YT app for it.